# Applying for Phd of international law

Tags: phd

Is it possible to apply for Phd of international law in US or Europe without bachelor's degree of law but graduated in master of international law?

Comment: Hi Angel, welcome to Academia.SE. Before asking a question like this, it is generally expected that you would do a least a little research and reference what you found. That way, people can be much more helpful to you and others who find your question relevant.

Comment: Try asking some admissions departments.